# Oracle APEX Complex programming

Tags: oracle-apex, dynamicquery

I have a Combo Box and I want to show some data when item is selected.
Assume the following data table

TRANS_ID    1
DATA_AR      تجريب
DATA_CH      测试
DATA_EN      Testing

and the application supposed to be shown as

Change Language? 
Some data on my website ... etc etc etc

Now, what ever I selects, I want to show the labels as per language.
Thanks in advance

Comment: so basically, you want to translate the application?

Comment: Yes!
some labels to be inserted in the Database then on selection of any language from a combo box, labels must be translated.

Answer (score 0):

## Managing Dynamic Labeling for APEX Form Fields

I prepared a simpler example to illustrate the possibility:

> - Create two form fields on your APEX Page Form.

[image: APEX Form Design Set Up]

> - Make `P00_NAME` for the Input field. (Where 'P00' = is the naming convention for a page-specific form item.)  This will also be the page item which will demonstrate the dynamic label value capability.
>
>   ***The key lesson to take from this demonstration is that a reference to a value carried by another page item value can be used to fill in the label value for that form element, as you will see later in the steps below.***

[image: APEX Form Item With Dynamic Label]

> - Make `P00_LABEL_NAME` and make it a `SELECT LIST` typed form input value.  Using the design wizard tool, make a STATIC selection list of "language" and "translated label" value pairs.

[image: Apex Form Item Which Changes the Language Setting]

For this demonstration, the following language key-pairs were used:

```
 PAGE ITEM LOV Definition:
 STATIC2:ENGLISH;HELLO,FRENCH;BONJOUR,ITALIAN;BONJOURNO,JAPANESE;KONNICHIWA,CHINESE;NIHAO,SPANISH;BUENOS DIAS
```

[image: Language and Label Value Pairs]

> - **Take a look at the form in action below:**

[image: APEX Sample Page with Dynamic Field Labeling]

Making a few changes and new selections of language choices within the statically defined list shows that the form label changes along with each selected language option.